How can I uncheck ALL checkboxes in an MFC ctreectrl?
I have a CMFCShellTreeCtrl myctree. While running the program, the user may select any element and I turn on its checkbox in the On_TvnSelChangedMFCshelltree code. (I need to disable ALL boxes so the user can't do it him/herself.) The user might then change his/her mind and select another item. Windows won't automatically uncheck the original box when I check this one so I must first tell Windows to uncheck ALL checkboxes in myctree (because I don't know the original one).
I realize that un-setting ALL of them may be a performance hit, so I "could" save a pointer to the one I set and unset it explicitly.
Currently, if the user selects one item, then selects another, they both stay checked. So the tree items are not exclusive. My desire is to use the checkboxes as a means for the user to have a visible reminder of where he was.

As you probably realize, the CMFCShellTreeCtrl is more of a "virtual" browsing tree - it does not actually generate a full expanded tree, but expands as-you-browse.  Hence, I don't think you can easily "uncheck all" (hence your question?).   There is a SelectPath method - that may be better mechanism to "restore" a "Selection" in lieu of a checkbox?  In that case, just save off the chosen "path" and then restore it via that method???

This all reads like you're trying to reinvent the TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS tree-view control style.

I want the virtual tree to retain visibility to all the visited/expanded nodes, so the user can change his selection. The checkbox acts as a virtual bookmark. But I only want the most recent bookmark to be available. From the above comments, I think I'm stuck with saving a reference to the selected item during ON_TvnSel... and unchecking it when I get to the ON_TvnSel...  again. At least thatway, I avoid the hit for iterating through all nodes myself.

Your question is very confuse. I could not understand if you want to uncheck all or disable all.

Just uncheck them so they are currently "not selected".
